# Unable to XML serialization when using .NET to consume REST Axis2 WS

Tags: c#, xml, linq, web-services, rest

I'm trying to consume an Axis2 REST XML response using C#.NET with RestSharp and Linq. However I can't seem to serialize the XML response either using RestSharp or manually.

This is an example of the XML response from Axis2:

```
<ns:response xmlns:ns="http://com.some.where" xmlns:ax2488="http://com.some.where/xsd">
<ns:return xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ax2488:Book">
    <ax2488:field1>Orson Scott Card</ax2488:field1>
    <ax2488:field1>Some One Else</ax2488:field1>
    <ax2488:field2>1</ax2488:field2>
    <ax2488:isbn10>142996393X</ax2488:isbn10>
    <ax2488:isbn13>9781429963930</ax2488:isbn13>
    <ax2488:date>2010</ax2488:date>
    <ax2488:blah>Tom Doherty Associates</ax2488:blah>
    <ax2488:ssss>on loan</ax2488:ssss>
    <ax2488:name>Ender's Game Volume 1 of The Ender Quintet</ax2488:name>
</ns:return>
```

When I try to get the elements out there using XElements (Linq), I always get null?

```
 var elements = root.Elements("Book");
```

I've tried a few different element names with no luck.

Also, using RestSharp, it successfully gets the first and only response, however if I have multiple responses, it returns null.

```
 var response1 = _client.Execute<Book>(request);
 var response2 = _client.Execute<List<Book>>(request);
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: From sample XML above, which element you tried to select? I can't see any `<Book>` element there.

Comment: I think that's fundamentally my problem. The `<Book>` element is what is between `<ns:return ... xsi:type="ax2488:Book">`

Answer (score 0):

One possible way, using `XDocument` with XPath query :

```
using System.Xml.XPath;

var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());

//register prefixes for use in XPath
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://com.some.where");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

var xpath = "//ns:response/ns:return[@xsi:type='ax2488:Book']";
//above xpath consists of path from root to <ns:return> : //ns:response/ns:return
//and criteria for <ns:return> : [@xsi:type='ax2488:Book']

var doc = XDocument.Load("path_to_xml_file.xml");
var returnElements = doc.XPathSelectElements(xpath, nsmgr);
```

I assumed that your XML structure looks about like this :

```
<root>
    <ns:response xmlns:ns="http://com.some.where" xmlns:ax2488="http://com.some.where/xsd">
        <ns:return xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ax2488:Book">
            <ax2488:field1>Orson Scott Card</ax2488:field1>
            <ax2488:field1>Some One Else</ax2488:field1>
            <ax2488:field2>1</ax2488:field2>
            <ax2488:isbn10>142996393X</ax2488:isbn10>
            <ax2488:isbn13>9781429963930</ax2488:isbn13>
            <ax2488:date>2010</ax2488:date>
            <ax2488:blah>Tom Doherty Associates</ax2488:blah>
            <ax2488:ssss>on loan</ax2488:ssss>
            <ax2488:name>Ender's Game Volume 1 of The Ender Quintet</ax2488:name>
        </ns:return>
    </ns:response>
    <ns:response xmlns:ns="http://com.some.where" xmlns:ax2488="http://com.some.where/xsd">
        ........
    </ns:response>
    ........
    ........
</root>
```